# How to convert a list in python to a numpy array to put into tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a deep learning model for [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/diabetic-retinopathy-detection/data). Because I'm working with a desktop, I am only using 3,000 images from the first training set, which I have in a folder on an external drive. I am using the following python code to get a list of images from the folder:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('/Volumes/G-DRIVE mobile USB-C/traan/*.jpeg'): #assuming jpeg
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)

print(image_list)
```

The list looks like this when its printed:

```
[<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=3888x2592 at 0x1087337D0>, <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=3888x2592 at 0x108733850>, ...
```

How do I take this list and convert it into a form that I can put into a tensor flow model, perhaps like the one in [this tutorial.](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification)

Comment: If you're getting started with tensorflow, I would recommend you to go through the tutorials offered by TensorFlow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/).

Comment: I have read those and they were helpful, but they dont really help with using my own data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first need to cast your list into a `numpy` array,

```
import numpy as np
images_list = np.stack(image_list) # assuming all the images have similar shape
                                   # i.e. (height, width, 3), images_list has now
                                   # shape (num_images, height, width, channel)
```

You can then use this tensor, or part of this tensor, to train your model using a placeholder

```
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, channel])
...
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={images:images_list})
```

Comment: Thanks! If my images are not the same size, how do I normalize the sizes?

Comment: You can resize them to have the same size using, for instance, `cv2.resize(image, (height, width))`.

Comment: Consider accepting this answer as the answer to your question and/or upvote it if it helped you :).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that.